# How to run reactjs (using create-react-app) on a server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

So I obviously can't access localhost:3000 on my server, so I wanted to test it via the ip address with subfolders e.g. (192.0.1.168/reactjs). I've run `npm run build` and I've gone into the build folder, but it displays an empty page.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you serve the index.html file?

Comment: @OleBläsing That's what I'm trying to figure out. I can get angular 2 to run fine (and easily enough). After running `npm run build` the index.html is in the build folder. But I have no idea how to serve it. I've even changed the `homepage` option... unless I've done that incorrectly. Not to mention the index.html comes up as blank.

Answer (score 2):

`npm run build` compiles your source files into a minified version of your app. This version can be found inside your /build directory.

If you want to serve this compiled version, you need to setup a webserver. Most common around are "Apache" and "nginx". Configure your webserver to use your /build directory as the root directory.

For configuration advices of your webserver you should read the documentation of the choosen one.

Comment: I'm using apache, I'm accessing the build directory directly e.g. `192.0.1.168/reactjs/build` but it's showing up as blank oddly.

Comment: Would you know how to change the build location?

Comment: You shouldn't change your homepage config for serving purposes. You should change configuration of your Apache to use build as the *root* directory. You can configure virtual hosts to host multiple projects on one server.

Comment: I'll have to look into virtual hosting as I have no idea how to use it. But for now, for development reasons, I'll just keep it as the `/build`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding `"homepage": "/reactjs/build",` to `package.json`. Didn't work before as I didn't put `build` in it as well.

So the next question is, how do I change the build location, so that I can access it via `www.website.com/reactjs` rather than `www.website.com/reactjs/build`.